# What is the difference between the ss-id and the ss-pid in ServiceStack sessions?

Tags: servicestack

What is the difference between the **ss-id** and the **ss-pid** in ServiceStack sessions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ss-id` is a temporary session id that is given to requests during a browsing session and thus expires when the browsing session ends, whereas `ss-pid` is a permanent session id, *i.e.* it should persist when the user closes their browser and later returns to your site, given that they haven't cleared cookies.

This is described here in [the Sessions documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions):

> When the SessionFeature is enabled, a Global RequestFilter is added to ServiceStack to ensure that all requests have a Temporary ss-id and a Permanent ss-pid session cookies set. These Cookies just contain a unique Base64-encoded Guid. The ss-opt cookie just stores the users preference on whether they want their current session to be temporary or permanent (i.e. to Remember Me or not - Default is Temporary). Permanent session cookie ss-pid will be created even if ss-opt is Temporary - that helps you to link subsequent requests together and can be used for user request analyzing.

I hope that helps.